# Django Rest_framework Apiview to show items

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a django api, to show the product count for each manufacturer as users add products in real time. I've tried this and it's not working, and I am getting a null constraint error when I want to add an item to my cart using the api.

Below are my serializers and api view codes:

```py
class CartViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CartDetailSerializer
    queryset = CartList.objects.all()


    #@detail_route(methods=['post', 'put'])
    def add_item(request, self, pk=None):
        cart = self.get_object()
        try:
            product = Product.objects.get(
                pk = request.data['product_id']
            )
            quantity = int(request.data['quantity'])
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
            return Response({'status': 'fail' })

        if product.quantity < 0 or product.quantity - quantity < 0:
            print('sorry check back leta')
            return Response({'status': 'fail'})
    
         existing_cart = CartList.objects.filter(product=product,       
            cart=cart).first()
        if existing_cart:
            existing_cart.quantity +=quantity
            existing_cart.save()
        else:
            new_cart = CartList(cart=cart, product=product,       
                  quantity=quantity)
            new_cart.save()
            product_list =      
        Product.Objects.filter(manufacturer=manufacturer).count()
        serializer = CartSerializer(cart)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

### Serializer

```py
class CartDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = UserSerializer(read_only =True)
    items = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CartList
        fields = ('id', 'customer', 'items', 'created', 'updated')


class CartListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CartList
        fields = ('product', 'quantity')
```

#### models

```
from django.db import models
from register.models import CustomUser
from product.models import Product, Manufacturer, Category
class CartList(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,  
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.customuser.email 

    def get_total_price(self):
        total_price = self.quantity * self.product.price
        return total_price
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide the details of how you have defined the CartList model. Most probably while defining the model you have not marked the columns as nullable.

Comment: Please show your Cart model

Comment: Below is my Carlist Model

Comment: i have show the model for my cartlist